# Ubuntu Mobile Broadband

Tags: mobile, ubuntu-18.04, modem, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am having trouble setting up cellular connection on my Jetson Nano to T-Mobile with a Huawei E220 stick. It used to be able to connect but it does not connect any more. PIN is disabled, and stick works fine under Windows. I think it might be related to the fact that Ubuntu Modem Manager misidentified the stick as E176?

Please advise.

```
p:~$ lsusb | grep Huawei
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
p:~$ mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [huawei] E176
p:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
p:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE                 CONNECTION         
eth0     ethernet  connected             Wired connection 1 
l4tbr0   bridge    connected             l4tbr0             
ttyUSB1  gsm       connecting (prepare)  T-Mo               
dummy0   dummy     unmanaged             --                 
rndis0   ethernet  unmanaged             --                 
usb0     ethernet  unmanaged             --                 
lo       loopback  unmanaged             --
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of mysterious connect/disconnects I put an USB extension cord between the Nano and the modem et voilà! Connection is robust now. Never mind how many lines you see in your connection icon, you might have reception issues if activation fails with msgs like these in your logs:

```
$ sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-10-25 12:49:30 CEST. --
okt 25 12:53:54 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000834.4694] device (ttyUSB1): Activation: starting connection 'T-Mobile Default' (94e66a1c-baa3-4d94-b439-80ca55d26735)
okt 25 12:53:54 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000834.4705] device (ttyUSB1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
okt 25 12:55:04 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000904.4144] connectivity: (l4tbr0) timed out
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <warn>  [1572000960.4562] modem-broadband[ttyUSB1]: failed to connect modem: Network timeout
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000960.4566] device (ttyUSB1): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'gsm-registration-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <warn>  [1572000960.4600] device (ttyUSB1): Activation: failed for connection 'T-Mobile Default'
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000960.4627] device (ttyUSB1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000960.4649] policy: auto-activating connection 'T-Mobile Default'
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000960.4679] device (ttyUSB1): Activation: starting connection 'T-Mobile Default' (94e66a1c-baa3-4d94-b439-80ca55d26735)
okt 25 12:56:00 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <info>  [1572000960.4690] device (ttyUSB1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
okt 25 12:58:06 jerry-desktop NetworkManager[3947]: <warn>  [1572001086.4517] modem-broadband[ttyUSB1]: failed to connect modem: Network timeout
```